# jQuery add class to parent if condition is true in child

Tags: jquery, css, parent, addclass

Is there a way I can use jQuery to add a class to the parent element if the child element meets a certain condition?

I want this code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="first.html">First</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a class="flyout-toggle" href="second.html">Second</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To change to this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="first.html">First</a>
  </li>
  <li class="has-flyout">
     <a class="flyout-toggle" href="second.html">Second</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('li:has(.flyout-toggle)').addClass('has-flyout')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a.flyout-toggle').parent().addClass('has-flyout');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `parent`

```
$(selector).parent().addClass('test');
```

In your case

```
$('.flyout-toggle').parent().addClass('has-flyout');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/bakV3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest` method

```
if(condition) {
   $('.flyout-toggle').closest('li').addClass('has-flyout');
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/D92Dg/)**